# Add month constraint to date_trunc by week

Tags: postgresql, time

I am trying to truncate several dates of a certain month to the start of the week, except the ones that start in the previous month.

**Example:**

Wednesday 5 Dec 2012 **should** be truncated to Monday 3 Dec 2012

Saturday 1 Dec 2012 **should not** be truncated to Monday 26 Nov 2012

For truncating the dates I am using:

```
date_trunc('week', dates.d)
```

The problem is that **Saturday 1 Dec 2012** still gets truncated to **Monday 26 Nov 2012**

Can I add a constraint to it, so that it takes the month into account?

Thanks in advance :)

NOTE: I am using version 9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GREATEST(date_trunc('week', dates.d), date_trunc('month', dates.d))
```